# How would I find the length of a linkedlist IN a linkedlist?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, traversal, removeclass

I'm trying to go through a linkedlist(which we can call the superlist) which has elements of linked lists(sublists) within it.

The method that adds the elements into both linked lists is:

```
LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();

public void add(Object... item) {
    LinkedList<Object> thingie = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Object i: item) {
        thingie.add(i);
    }
    list.addAll(thingie);
}
```

Now I have to write methods to check if there are groups of 1, 2, 3, 4 elements in the sublists by traversing the superlist
What I have so far (which is very wrong) is:

```
LinkedList <Object> ohno = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
            ohno = (LinkedList<Object>) list.get(i);
            if (int j = 1; j = ohno.size();){
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
```

Comment: Your super list `list` is just a list of objects and not a list of `LinkedList`.

Comment: I think you want `if (i == ohno.size() - 1){`

Comment: What do you mean by _"check if there are groups of 1, 2, 3, 4 elements "_? How will you be using that information?

Comment: so if I call the method hasSingle(); it will search through and find a linkedlist with 1 name object in it, and return true.

Comment: @Abhishek How is the super list not a `LinkedList`?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis It itself is a `LinkedList` but not a list of `LinkedList`. The OP is trying to cast elements of `list` to `LinkedList` inside the for loop which may result in `ClassCastException` in case objects getting added to `thingie` are not `LinkedList` themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a method that passes a parameter for the group size in question and finds out if there are any sub lists of size group size.

```
private static boolean hasSubListsOfSize (LinkedList<Object> superList, final int groupSize)
{
     for (int i = 0, size = superList.size(); i < size; i++)
     {
         LinkedList<Object> subList = (LinkedList<Object>) superList.get(i);
         if (subList.size() == groupSize)
         {
            return true;
         }
     }

     // didn't find any sub lists of the group size
     return false;
}
```

**Side Note**: As pointed out by @Abhishek your super List is technically not a `LinkedList` of `LinkedList's`. It is a `LinkedList` of `Objects`. That's why you have to do the explicit cast to LinkedList to access the "Sub LinkedList's".

If you want a true `LinkedList` of `LinkedList's`, then you should create the superList like this:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>> superList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>>();
```

If you create it that way, then you will avoid having to do the explicit casts at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive simple solution

```
def getCount(head):
    if (not node): # Base case
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + getCount(head.next)
```